# getting an error while making an object from a class

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is a code for my school pls help

```
 class product:
    deliveryCharge=50
    def __init__(self,nam="Teddy Bear", prc=500):
        self.name=nam
        self.price=prc
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_price(self):
        return self.price + product.deliveryCharge
    def __str__(self):
        return "The {} will cost you Rs.{}.".format(self.get_name(),self.get_price())
        
    class gift(product):
    def __init__(self,nam,prc,wrpchrge=100):
        super().__init__(nam,prc)
        self.wrappingcharge=wrpchrge
    
    def get_price(self):
        return self.price + product.deliveryCharge+gift.wrappingcharge
    
    x1=product("yoyo",29)
    print("I am buying a {} and it costs me {}".format(x1.get_name,x1.get_price))
    m1=gift("yoyo",29)
    print("I am buying a {} and it costs me {}".format(m1.get_name,m1.get_price))
    print(product.get_name)
```

The error I am getting:
[image: Error]

If anyone knows how to fix this,

Comment: Don't include spam in your question...

Comment: Where is the error?!

Comment: You are printing the reference to the objects in memory. Use parenthesis to print the actual values.

Comment: why can't you copy/paste the terminal output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are printing the reference to the objects in memory. Use parenthesis to print the actual values. For instance `x1.get_name` should be `x1.get_name()`. There are also other problems, you need to use self to reference the values in both classes, even in the gift class for values in product, since it inherits its functions.

Here's an example:

```
class product:
    deliveryCharge=50
    def __init__(self,nam="Teddy Bear", prc=500):
        self.name=nam
        self.price=prc
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_price(self):
        return self.price + self.deliveryCharge # changed from product to self
    def __str__(self):
        return "The {} will cost you Rs.{}.".format(self.get_name(),self.get_price())
    
class gift(product):
    def __init__(self,nam,prc,wrpchrge=100):
        super().__init__(nam,prc)
        self.wrappingcharge=wrpchrge

    def get_price(self):
        return self.price + self.deliveryCharge+self.wrappingcharge # changed to self

x1=product("yoyo",29)
print("I am buying a {} and it costs me {}".format(x1.get_name(),x1.get_price()))
m1=gift("yoyo",29)
print("I am buying a {} and it costs me {}".format(m1.get_name(),m1.get_price()))
print(x1.get_name()) # changed to x1 from product
```

Result:

```
I am buying a yoyo and it costs me 79
I am buying a yoyo and it costs me 179
yoyo
```